# C++ - Smart Reference Member Access

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, smart-pointers, member

I am working on a type of smart reference for an array class. Similar to std::vector. It works wonderfully, except when I want to access a member function of the masked class, then it fails. I am fairly sure that I cannot overload the . operator (sadly), but I need some kind of work around.

My goal is to be able to do something like

```
array[10].size()
```

The execution should go
  Get 10th element as a smart reference
  Call size() on the element masked by the smart reference

Is there any hope? I already have operators that do conversion

```
operator masked_type ();
operator masked_type& ();
```

To clarify, based on a question below, I am modeling an array as a table in a database where the key is the index of the array. I read from the database, store it in a pointer, return a smart reference which can be modified via the equality operator, and upon going out of scope it updates the database based on various conditions. So, the "smart reference" is not a simple reference to a datatype.

Comment: Could you overload operator -> ?

Comment: That would require the "reference" to be a pointer mask right? Because then array[10]->size() looks like an array of pointers. Or am I missing something? Would this help the compiler to understand array[10].size()?

Comment: is this acceptable array[10] >> size() ?

Comment: Thank you both, but it is kind of unnatural. I would like this to also permit array[10][5] I think this demands something different.

Comment: `That would require the "reference" to be a pointer mask right?` no, it would require 'something' which has -> operator. Basically, some kind of fly-by class which knows how to get to size on op->

Comment: There are no smart references in C++. If you want to be able to call `x.size()`, `x` must have a member named `size`. There is no way around it.

Comment: I removed my answer, as it is not really an answer. The use of `operator->` was already mentioned by Severin as the comment.  If you really think this needs to be *answered* you can create an answer yourself and accept it